# How to set keyboard shortcut to ctrl-right arrow in Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On the Mac version of VSCode, how do I set the keyboard shortcut of word right (cursorWordStartRight) to ctrl-rightArrow (as is standard in Windows)?

It used to work but now when I try to assign it from the keyboard shortcuts page where it says "Press desired key combination and press ENTER" it does not register ctrl-right (but it'll register cmd-right though)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with the keyboard shortcut being used at the OS / desktop environment level. For more info on that, see [macOS: Navigating between desktops using keyboard shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/362614/479746).

If you don't have any conflicts with keyboard shortcuts registered at the OS / desktop environment level, and for some reason you still can't enter the keyboard shortcut via VS Code's keyboard shortcut UI editor, you can just write it out in the keybindings.json files directly. You can open that file using the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` file in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). Ex.

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+right",
    "command": "cursorWordStartRight",
    "when": "editorFocus",
},
```

Also, in case any reader is unaware, I think macOS already has bindings for this via <kbd>opt</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.